# Is this ok to write A of B as a singular noun of plural nouns?

Tags: grammar

As a non-native speaker and an engineer, I'm always confusing with these kinds of expressions. Can anybody help me understand clearly?
I have a specific example.

- A of B: When A and B are nouns, but B is plural.

example 1) **The modulus** of sample 1, sample 2 and sample 3 are measured by a tensile machine.

In this case, is **the modulus** ok or should I say **the moduli** ?

Thanks so much.
Best,

Answer (score 2):

I think it's grammatically correct to use the plural form for A. You are doing three separate modulus measurements to get three separate moduli (as also indicated by the plural form of the verb "are") so the plural form should be used. Consider these possibilities:

1. The **weight** of sample1, sample2 and sample3 **is** measured by the machine
2. The **weights** of sample1, sample2 and sample3 **are** measured by the machine

Sentence 1 implies that the machine does one weighing to determine the combined weight of the three samples (though, in reality, you'd probably explicitly say "The combined weight of..." to avoid any doubt). Sentence 2 implies that each sample is weighed separately so we know how much each one weighs individually. Note how weight/weights agree with is/are.

Your version is confusing: "The weight of sample1, sample2 and sample3 are measured by the machine." How many weighings take place? One or three?

The rule can be modified by common sense. If I write

1. The height of the cows is measured by the machine
2. The heights of the cows are measured by the machine

Both sentences will be interpreted the same way - each cow is measured individually. Because even though (1) *could* be taken to mean that the cows stand on eachothers shoulders and are measured all at once, that would be ridiculous and so obvously isn't what's meant.

The only thing that gives me any pause is that "modulus" is an uncommon word, and latinate plurals like "moduli" are uncommon in English. So a person unfamiliar with the term might not realise that "moduli" is the plural of "modulus." If that's likely to be a problem with your intended audience, you could rephrase like this to avoid the problem altogether:

The tensile machine measures the modulus of each of sample1, sample2 and sample3.

Comment: Hi Chris,  Thank you so much! it makes me clear to understand. I meant to measure the modulus of sample 1, sample 2 and sample 3. Now I understand I should use the plural form.